# java realm data model design -- could it be better?

Tags: android, realm

the code below is not complete and the actual implementation is quite verbose , so am mostly looking for help with the logic

basically i have json array with dynamic object types, i can pass to recycler view correctly but having trouble persisting since the model is very dynamic, i resulted to use realm to persist , i procede to store each data in relation model base on data type , and null for the object .

json data structure

```
[
  {
    type: event // or peep  
    ... // corresponding items like title or date ..
  },
  {type:peeps
  ...
  },

  ...
]
```

### am looking if possible a better implementation than the one i have

Implement  --

```
public class Feeds extends RealmObject {

    public String  Type;



}

public class Peeps extends RealmObject {
    public int Id;
    private string owner ;
    //...
}

public class Event extends RealmObject {
    public int Id;
    private String title ;
    //...
}
```

then on recycler onbindview we get the corresponding data type

```
Feed.type == event  title ;
titleview.setText ( feed.event.getitle())
```

Comment: Why the data block?

Comment: That is not valid JSON and that is not valid Java code.

Comment: Also, you'll hate parsing that "very dynamic" JSON. Most well-designed APIs return one particular data-structure for a particular backend endpoint. If the server's responses are in your hands, I'd reevaluate it completely, because this makes it quite impossible to work using high-quality tools like Retrofit and Gson (or LoganSquare). Having a `type` in your JSON is a pain in the ass.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks but i have event ,pictures and video data all in the single feed , which am rendering with different layout , using the the `getItemType` i realise using type isnt perfect which is why am here , am mostly implying my JS knowledge , which json is very flexible --- can you give a guide source or something that could help me . thanks

Comment: ...if you need a unified response, then that should be like `{"events": [{...}], "videos": [{...}], "peeps": [{...}]}`

Comment: but i need to parse all of them into one feed , also parse by item -- it is initially loaded different as events ,vidoes , but i am rendering them in a single recycler view -- as such i marsh them into a single array on the server , other by last_update_time -- so the app recieves this marshup array -- is there another way to do these ?

Comment: In that case, I'd just use 1 class for all objects to parse the JSON,  and 1 class for the RealmObject that represents all feed items.

Comment: could you please expand, as much as these is working for i realise it wont scale -- soo any example or source to read would be appreciated